# Environment Variable UID not found in C++ program

Tags: c++, bash, g++, environment-variables

Can someone explain why I can expand `PATH` but not `UID` with below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::string ExpandEnvironmentVariables(std::string path)
{
    static std::regex env("\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}");
    std::smatch match;
    while (std::regex_search(path, match, env))
    {
        const char * s = getenv(match[1].str().c_str());
        const std::string var(s == NULL ? "(empty)" : s);
        path.replace(match[0].first, match[0].second, var);
    }

    return path;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string UID = "${UID}";
    std::cout << UID << " ==> " << ExpandEnvironmentVariables(UID) <<  std::endl;

    std::string PATH = "${PATH}";
    std::cout << PATH << " ==> " << ExpandEnvironmentVariables(PATH) <<  std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
./ExpandEnvironmentVariables
${UID} ==> (empty)
${PATH} ==> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

UID variable exist in bash:

```
echo $UID
1000
```

Comment: I believe UID is  an internal Bash variable that is not actually part of the exported environment, and so not accessble via `getenv`, but which bash allows to be accessed via the $var syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all shell variables are exported in bash.  You can examine the shell variable status like this:

```
$ declare -p UID
declare -ir UID="1000"
```

This means that the variable has the integer attribute (`-i`) and that it is read-only `-r`).  An exported variable looks like this:

```
$ declare -p PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

The `-x` means that the variable is exported and added to the process environment of subprocesses.

Comment: So I have to use `getuid()` - That gives me the proper `UID` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)

Comment: @SBF: Consider whether you want to fuss about the EUID (effective UID — `geteuid()`) versus the real UID (`getuid()`).  The chances are that you won't want to handle the complexities, not least because most of the time the results will be the same.  But if they're different, which you use matters — and depends on what you're trying to track.  Environment variables are not dreadfully reliable, in general.  What happens if someone runs `UID=0 bash -c 'echo $UID'`? (Partial answer: `bash` says it is a readonly variable — but I'd not want to bet the security of the firm on there being no evasion!)

Comment: I understand UID/EUID are read-only but why aren't they exported? I don't like to hardcode the path I need to store a daemon's pid file so I want to use `/var/run/user/${UID}/mydaemon.pid` instead of `/var/run/user/1000/sbfspotupload.pid` - Anyway, I tested with `getuid()` and this  works very well. I can adapt my code to handle the special UID/EUID variables.

Comment: Just to clarify, the path of this directory should be read from the [`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` variable](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).